# Opinion on Python exceptions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Just looking for opinions on which is the best way to use exceptions?

Should the exception handling go inside the function or should it go outside the function when you actually call the function. For example, we could have the following function:

```
def divideMe(a,b):

     return a/b
```

This function is risky because there is a chance that if the calling program passes a value of 0 in for the argument b then the function would divide by zero and an exception would be raised. So the question is should you put the exception handling inside the function and handle it like this:

```
def divideMe(a,b):

     try:

          return a/b

     except Exception:

          return 0
```

OR should the calling program catch and handle the exception, like this:

```
try:

   result = divideMe(x,y)

except Exception:

   print("You entered 0 in for denominator")
```

Comment: Hi Alicia, unfortunately it's impossible to answer your question. I can make reasonable arguments that either are good - much like I'm sure you can, and is why you're asking this question. However deciding which is better comes down to the scenario that you're working in. And so to be able to even start thinking of answering this we'd need to know how and why it's being called. Since this is Code Review, if you have a situation that has brought about this question; then providing the calling function is likely to be received better.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: def divide(a, b):
   ...:     return a / b
   ...: 


In [5]: try:
   ...:     result = divide("a", 5)
   ...: except Exception:
   ...:     print("You entered 0 in for denominator")
   ...:     
You entered 0 in for denominator
```

See the problem? Exceptions were invented to release the libraries from the burden to guess what beahiour the user wants for all kind of errors. Libraries shall not `print` but leave it to the caller. The caller is the only one to know how to react on different kind of exceptions. So if you catch, be specific.

Comment: Please refrain from answering off-topic questions.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what the function dose and what the error is, because the "divide" function dose division, and because the DevideByzero error is about division, the function should handle it, but if you were handling TypeErrors, for example that should be outside of the function.

Comment: Please refrain from answering low-quality questions that are likely to get closed.  Once you've answered, that [limits what can be done to improve the question](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body), making it more likely that your efforts are wasted.  It's better to wait until the question is properly ready before you answer!

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, you should allow exceptions to percolate back to the caller; this makes it easier for the caller to find bugs in their own code.  A function should have a clear "contract" with its caller that will typically include raising an exception if the caller passes it invalid arguments.  If part of your function's contract is that it will catch invalid arguments and return a default value in that case, make sure that's explicit in the docstring and/or name of the function:

```
def divide(a, b):
    """Divide a by b.  Raises an exception if a and b are not divisible."""
    return a / b

def safe_divide(a, b):
    """Divide a by b.  Returns zero if a and b are not divisible for any reason."""
    try:
        return a / b
    except:
        return 0
```

As a general rule, a bare `except` is bad practice and you should instead catch specific exceptions.  For example, this code:

```
try:
   result = x / y
except Exception:
   print("You entered 0 in for denominator")
```

is incorrect because there are failure modes other than `y` being zero.  Better exception handling might look like this:

```
try:
    result = x / y
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("You entered 0 in for denominator")
except TypeError:
    print("One of these things is not a number")
```

If an exception is raised that you completely didn't expect, it's better to **not** catch it so that it will cause your program to fail hard and fast; this makes it easier for you to find your bug and fix it.

Comment: Don't answer off-topic questions.

Comment: This question doesn't look off-topic to me, but I respect your opinion.

Comment: Then you clearly don't know the rules.

Comment: It ticks all the boxes from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, at least with a charitable reading (and why be uncharitable?).  If it's in violation of other rules, then yes, I don't know those rules.

Comment: @SamStafford I think it fails the question about hypothetical code: "Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or hypothetical code?"

Comment: I will agree with you, from that page it may seem on-topic. And if you're uncharitable then you may mark it against the "Is it actual code from a project" reason. However it is asking about a generic best practice, and so is part of the "Missing Review Context" close reason, specifically, "generic best practices are outside the scope of this site." It is best if you validate against [this meta post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3649) rather than the help center.

Comment: I don't actually know for certain that it's not actual code from a project. It would be a very beginner-level project, certainly, but I'm not going to get in the business of demanding to see people's github pages and assessing the maturity level of their project before looking at their code, nor am I going to get in the business of reviewing every meta post on a regular cadence.  As I said, though, I respect your downvote and your opinion, and I also hope OP gets something useful from my answer.

Comment: I know the question is closed and I appreciate all answers! There was not an actual code for this yet I am still learning python and coding in general and my teacher said to try a forum with experienced coding people. I can only assume that I will very soon have a code requiring this. But again Thanks to all who were helpful!! And sorry Mods I thought it had enough context for everyone to understand that I was wanting an idea on using exceptions as I am sure I will very soon have to do or use something similar the this example (with more information of course).

Comment: @SamStafford You've compleatly missed the point. "if you're uncharitable" isn't the reason it's off-topic.